# How to solve this error while downloading stopwords using nltk

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, nltk, stop-words

import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')

from nltk.corpus import stopwords

stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))
I run this code in kaggle notebooks. But I am getting following error.
[nltk_data] Error loading stopwords: <urlopen error [Errno -3]
[nltk_data]     Temporary failure in name resolution>

Could anyone help me in solving this error

I am trying to download stopwords. But unable to do it